# Android: Using Windowmanager to make the HOME button unwork

Tags: android, window-managers

I have already finished an `Android lock-screen app` but my teacher asks me to change it into an app using `Windowmanager` so that users can not exit the app using `HOME` button. The idea is that we can make the whole app be a float `full-screen window`. But I don't know how to change a finished `activity` into a `float window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't override the HOME button (or "make the HOME button unwork").

There was a time, about in Android 1.6 when you could do that, against Google's wishes. But now you just can't.

Think about it. If you could do that, some app you downloaded from the PlayStore could do that and render your phone unusable.

The closest you can get is adding CATEGORY_HOME as an intent of one of your activities. That way when the user touches the HOME button, he will be presented with the option to choose which activity will open when they touch HOME.

Here you've got an example on how to do it (you don't have to change anything in the Activity classs):

```
 <activity           
    android:name="com.mpascual.example.HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

This line is the relevant one (everything else is just an example):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has worked. But my app still has one problem: my app is a lock-screen app, so that the service is always running in the background. That means when i am running my other app on my phone, the HOME button will start my lock-screen app.....How can i resolve it?

Comment: I didn't get it. Anywya, seems like the question was answered and you are asking another wholy different question